# Google BigQuery vs Spark and Parquet

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, parquet

How does Google BigQuery compare to Apache Spark SQL and Parquet?

Is it correct to say that BigQuery is actually Storage & Analysis, and that you could therefore split the product into BigQuery Storage and BigQuery Analysis?

I understand there are plenty of other storage mechanisms, and processing engines, but, to pick 2 "pairs"...

For my understanding, is it a correct to say that BigQuery Storage is comparable with Apache Parquet and BigQuery Analysis is comparable with Spark SQL?

Is it correct to say that BigQuery storage is actually called Capacitor... "BigQuery’s next-generation columnar storage format"?

Is it also correct to say that Apache Parquet and BigQuery Storage both provide an implementation of Dremel?

Answer (score 2):

Capacitor is the file format used by BigQuery, while the storage is the whole distributed system to host the files & data. Dremel is the underlying execution engine. Here is some introduction (https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/01/bigquery-under-the-hood).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Bigquery keeps storage and compute separate. when you run a query data is loaded from Colossus to Dremel engine through the Jupiter network.

- collosus is the successor to GFS (Google File System). It actually stores the data.
- capacitor is the format in which data is stored inside collosus.
- Dremel is the engine which processes your query in a distribute fashion across multiple machines.
- Jupiter is the petabyte network which allows for very fast transfer of data from colossus to Dremel for processing.

The Apache Parquet is columnar data storage format similar to capacitor based on ideas from google's Dremel paper.

The Apache spark SQL is similar to dremel engine as it is also used for distributes query processing.

*references:*

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/new-blog-series-bigquery-explained-overview

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/bigquery/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format

https://www.systutorials.com/colossus-successor-to-google-file-system-gfs